# text is grainy/blurry when drawing text on a canvas via onload

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I try to draw text to my canvas at the onload event, the text shows up blurry.  I draw to the same canvas later via a button click from another function and it's fine.  But if I call this function from the button, it's still blurry.  Can anybody see something wrong in this code?

```
window.onload = initCanvasRender;

function initCanvasRender() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = '20px Times New Roman';
  ctx.fillText('hello...', c.width/2, c.height/2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some problem with the

```
ctx.fillText('hello...', c.width/2, c.height/2);
```

Because if you for example set width of the canvas with css then `c.width` and `c.height` will be the default size for the canvas which is, 300x150 and not the size defined in css. Try to set two variables for the width and height that are global for your application. E.g

```
var canvasWidth = 400;
var canvasHeight = 200;
c.width = canvasWidth;
c.height = canvasHeight;
/* ... */
```

and then later in your code you can use `canvasWidth` and `canvasWeight`:

```
ctx.fillText('hello...', canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2);
```

Take a look at this test: http://jsfiddle.net/EsQfb/7/ it's important to use use the `canvas.width` and not `canvas.style.width` in your case.

Take a look at this for more information about this: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width

Comment: Thanks!  The dev tools debugger showed I was getting 300x150, so you were right on.

Comment: Width and Height must be set as canvas attribute and not on CSS. if you set the size of canvas using css the canvas 'bitmap' is streched to reflect the new size. so `<canvas width='400px' height='200'>` must be used always.