# Blurry text/font on canvas element

Tags: android, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

**I am getting blurry text/font on a canvas only in FireFox (Android).** I am testing on a Nexus 7 (2013) which has a devicePixelRatio of 2. I have already combated the high density screens by using [this article on html5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/). This works absolutely fantastic for all of my desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE 10) and Chrome for Android.

I have searched the issue and found [someone having a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796370/text-is-grainy-blurry-when-drawing-text-on-a-canvas-via-onload) with onload being blurry. So I created this test: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/rjLaC/ but there is no difference between onload and manual generation from button in any browser.

My actual project is making tag elements:

### [Demo: jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/fgyqz/)

Preview (**Chrome desktop** v. 30.0.1599.69):

[image: Fiddle preview in Chrome Desktop: tags]

Preview large because nexus has high pixel density (**Chrome Android** v. 30.0.1599.82):

[image: Fiddle preview in Chrome Android: tags]

Preview (**Firefox desktop** v. 24.0):

[image: Fiddle preview in Firefox Desktop: tags]

Preview large because nexus has high pixel density (**FireFox Android** v. 24.0):

[image: Fiddle preview in Firefox Android: tags]

**I have no idea what is making the FireFox render blurry.**

Here is my implementation of the [HTML5 Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/):

```
// ...
// React to high pixel density (retina) screens
var hdCanvasWidth = rectX + rectWidth + 1;
var hdCanvasHeight = rectY + rectHeight + .5;
/* * /
$(element).attr({
    'width': hdCanvasWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
    'height': hdCanvasHeight * window.devicePixelRatio
});
/* */

// finally query the various pixel ratios
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
backingStoreRatio = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                    context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                    context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                    context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                    context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1,

ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio;

// ensure we have a value set for auto.
// If auto is set to false then we
// will simply not upscale the canvas
// and the default behaviour will be maintained
if (typeof auto === 'undefined') {
    auto = true;
}

// upscale the canvas if the two ratios don't match
if (auto && devicePixelRatio !== backingStoreRatio) {

    $(element).attr({
        'width': hdCanvasWidth * ratio,
        'height': hdCanvasHeight * ratio
    });

    $(element).css({
        'width': hdCanvasWidth + 'px',
        'height': hdCanvasHeight + 'px'
    });

    // now scale the context to counter
    // the fact that we've manually scaled
    // our canvas element
    context.scale(ratio, ratio);

}
// No weird ppi so just resize canvas to fit the tag
else
{
    $(element).attr({
        'width': hdCanvasWidth,
        'height': hdCanvasHeight
    });
}
// ...
```

Comment: 1) i don't get the +1 and +0.5 you do on start on width/height. 2) i would try shifting by (0.5;0.5) the canvas before the scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer a problem in FireFox for Android.

I just tested with FireFox 28.0.1 on Android 4.4.2 and it is completely crisp.